# How to create a MC package in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

How do I add an MC package on Pharo (version 3.0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Max's answer is correct, but you typically would not create an MC Package directly. Usually, you would create a package in the code browser. For example you could:

- Accept a class definition specifying an unknown category
- "Add Package…" from the package pane context menu
- Implement an extension method in an extension protocol specifying an unknown package

In all these cases, a Pharo system package (specifically anRPackage) will be created, as well as an MC package of the same name.

If for some special reason you need to create *just* an MC package, following Max's instructions will accomplish that.

n.b. while Max's assertion that packages include sub-categories like MyPackage-Core is true in general, it is not true if there is a package that is a better match. So if there was a Pharo package MyPackage-Core, then it would hold all code categorized MyPackage-Core[-.*], while MyPackage would hold all other MyPackage[-.*]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the world menu by clicking into the empty world
2. Select `Monticello Browser`
3. Click on `+Package` in the upper left corner
4. enter the name of the package you want to version (must be equivalent to the package name you use to put your packages in)

#### Note on package names

`-` acts as a sub package separator, i.e. you can have multiple Monticello packages with the same prefix such as `MyPackage-Core-Model`, `MyPackage-Core-View` and `MyPackage-Tests`. If you create a Monticello package with the name `MyPackage` it will include *all* of the sub packages (i.e. all three of the above), if you name it `MyPackage-Core` it will contain the packages `MyPackage-Core-Model` and `MyPackage-Core-View`.

To add repositories to the package (to which it can be saved):

1. deselect any selected package in the Monticello browser by clicking on such a package
2. select a repository from the panel on the right
3. right click that entry
4. select `Add to package...` from the context menu
5. select the package from the dialog

If you don't have the repository you need yet, create it using the `+Repository` button at the top.